# Client with WCF who needs admin rights

Tags: c#, web-services, http, wcf, client

According to the task, it is necessary to transfer the WCF http services to the client from the server. Migrate migrated, but these services need administrator rights. The client does not have administrator rights and cannot get them in any way. And I understand the essence of the problem: that you need to register http addresses for listening using:

`netsh http add urlacl url =% URL% user =% USER%.`

But as already said, no one will give administrator rights, and this command is executed only under them.

Can you please tell me if you can somehow avoid registering addresses for listening (which is unlikely) or are there any alternative options?

P.S. transfer services from the server to the client is stupid, I know. But such a task.

Comment: Usually the server-side needs administrator rights because the server needs the port number, and the client does not need the port number, so administrator rights are not required. Does your client also need to enable the port?

Comment: Yes, but he has no rights.

Comment: Desicion:

`http://0.0.0.0:80/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/%LOCALOATH%` OR `http://localhost:80/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/%LOCALOATH%` OR `http://localhost/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/%LOCALOATH%`